# Could anyone help explain what "primitive" mean in programming languages?

Tags: definition

I stumbled upon a Rust library called memchr at https://github.com/BurntSushi/memchr. The website states that

> This library provides heavily optimized routines for string search primitives.

I searched around and found that "primitive" is a term in computing for programming languages. Wikipedia states that

> In computing, language primitives are the simplest elements available in a programming language. A primitive is the smallest 'unit of processing' available to a programmer of a given machine, or can be an atomic element of an expression in a language.

But I'm still not able to fully understand it. Could anyone give me some examples of primitives in a language like Javascript? What exactly is "string search primitives"?

Answer (score 9):

In general, just like the name itself explain “primitive”, meaning that they are the most basic building blocks in a programing language. A data type that is built into a programming language, other than that you will need to create yourself a data type like object, array.

In javascripts, object and array are not primitive types because you need to create them from other primitive types like string, number, boolean… etc.

In short, Primitive types are types that not constructed from any other types and you cannot find any other smaller types within themself.

Answer (score 4):

To use JavaScript as an example, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) defines a primitive as

> In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods. There are 7 primitive data types: string, number, bigint, boolean, undefined, symbol, and null.

In my experience, I also see these called "Built-in" data types, that act as the building blocks for more complex data types. Typically, you won't be able to modify the behaviour of primitives in a programming language, but you will be able to **extend** their behaviour, my incorporating them into a data type you create yourself.

Returning to your original question of '**string search primitives**', I would assume that this is a primitive type that is used for searching and matching strings for certain values, i.e. substrings, potentially it could be this searcher type documented [here on the Rust wiki](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Searcher.html),

> Trait std::str::pattern::SearcherCopy
>
> A searcher for a string pattern.
>
> This trait provides methods for searching for non-overlapping matches
> of a pattern starting from the front (left) of a string.

but I could be mistaken as Rust isn't one of my heavily used language.

Answer (score 0):

For a Java example, a primitive type would be "char" (or characters) since it is one of the most basic types in the Java language. The String type, in Java, is labeled as  an Object type.